# How to group timestamp by week in typescript / ionic 2?

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic2, timestamp, filtering

I've put the below json into an array called logs and would like to group that weekly using the created timestamp.

```
{
  created : "2017-07-15 09:49:37"
  entry : "this is a log entry"
}
  created : "2017-07-13 09:49:37"
  entry : "this is a log entry"
}
{
  created : "2016-05-13 11:00:21"
  entry : "this is another log entry"
}
```

and the ionic 2 html.

```
<div *ngFor="let log of logs">
      <ion-list-header>
          {{log.created}}
      </ion-list-header>
     <ion-item>
         {{log.entry}}
     </ion-item>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Ok I've now done the weekly grouping in PHP which returns the below Json,

```
"payload": {
"logs": {
  "19": [
    "[{\"entry\":"this is an entry",\"created\":\"2017-05-12 09:51:18\"}]"
  ],
  "28": [
    "[{\"entry\":"this is an entry",\"created\":\"2017-07-15 09:50:50\"}]",
    "[{\"entry\":"this is an entry",\"created\":\"2017-07-15 09:51:18\"}]"
  ]
}
```

I receive it like so,

```
private weeks: any[];

this.api.getLogs().subscribe(
      data => {
        // Success
        this.weeks = data.payload.logs;
      },
      err => {
        //Err
      }
    );
```

and I attempt to use it in Ionic 2,

```
<div *ngFor="let week of weeks">
    <div *ngFor="let log of week">
        {{log.created}}
    </div>
</div>
```

but that gives me the below error,

```
Runtime Error
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post to show my current situation.  I've grouped by weeks in the php side but I'm having issues getting the json into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `weeks` as an array of any (`private weeks: any[];`) but you set it with a JSON (`data.payload.logs` is a JSON), so it seems that you have at least a type error here.